# Add separation between entries when logging error with full stacktrace

Tags: python, logging, error-logging

I'm currently logging errors with full stacktrace using the `logging` module with `exc_info=True`.

But the result is really difficult to parse visually, since the exceptions are logged with no seperator between them. This gets even worse when you using the `raise ... from` syntax, since the output of that includes blank lines, so your eyes are drawn to somewhere in the middle of the stacktrace, not the beginning.

How can I get a better formatting? Something like a line of ------- after each stacktrace would do.

Code Example:

```
#Setup
import logging

def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO, removeExistingHandlers=True):
    """Function setup different loggers as you want"""
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    #remove existing handlers
    ##without this, running the script multiple times means the log filess will be added as handlers
    ##multiple times, and every warning gets written into the log multiple times
    if removeExistingHandlers:
        existingHandlers = logger.handlers.copy()
        for exHandler in existingHandlers:
            logger.removeHandler(exHandler)

    #add new handler
    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger


def do_something():
    try:
        raise Exception("ok")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("WORSE") from e

errorLog = setup_logger('stacktrace_logger', 'err.log')

#Use
try:
    raise Exception("bad")
except Exception as e:
    errorLog.error(e, exc_info=True)

try:
    do_something()
except Exception as e:
    errorLog.error(e, exc_info=True)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Qix-/better-exceptions, maybe that solves your problem?

Comment: That might make exceptions easier to parse, but I don't see it helping to differentiate between the logs of different exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of a custom formatter that does the job, based on Bruno's suggestion.

```
class SeperatedExcFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        result = super().formatException(exc_info)
        if exc_info:
            result = result + "\n------------------------------------------------"
        return result
```

To use, replace `formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')` with `formatter = SeperatedExcFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a custom formatter, cf https://docs.python.org/fr/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#customized-exception-formatting